# Move designed VBA Userform by moving code between IDE environments

Tags: forms, vba, import, export

I am coding a project in VBA that will involve userforms. My issue is my current  IDE MS Excel, is not compatible (at least I think) with the destination IDE which is proprietary using lvb files. I will have to code as much as possible in MS VB Editor and cut and paste it into a blank file. That is fine for procedures and functions, but I do not think it would work for the forms. Where does the code sit that has the actual form guts, not the event stuff? If I could find that maybe I could past the form into the new IDE or something.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the UserForm and export it:

[image: Export form]

For UserForms, this actually results in *2* files - one for the code (.frm), and one for the designer (.frx).

[image: File explorer]

<sub>Ignore the Visual FoxPro Report association, I need to fix that...</sub>

When you re-import the file into the other IDE, it will check to see if there is a matching .frx file for the .frm file and import them both.

Comment: Note, *Microsoft Visual FoxPro Report* isn't the description for a .frx file when you don't have MS FoxPro installed (geez *who* has that installed anyway?!) - if you have Visual Studio 6 installed it might read something like *Visual Basic Binary Form File* or similar. And if you don't have VS6 installed, there might not be a file type description at all.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - For the DOS and UNIX versions?  :shudders: